# Extra Block Types (EBT) settings error after push

Tags: 10

I've added and enabled the Extra Block Types, Core and Core Remover Helper, modules on my local site. Enabling them also enabled multiple dependencies including Field and Field Group.

The site works fine locally, but I just pushed it to Pantheon dev and I get an error. Clearing the caches (either the button on dev, or via Terminus) didn't help.

Looking at the error logs, I see these errors.

> Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginException: Plugin (field_group_accordion) instance class Drupal\field_group\Element\Accordion does not exist. at /code/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Factory/DefaultFactory.php line 97

> Unable to determine class for field type 'ebt_settings' found in the 'field.storage.block_content.field_ebt_settings' configuration at /code/web/core/modules/field/src/FieldStorageConfigStorage.php line 167

I see that there is an *Extra Block Types (EBT): Accordion / FAQ* module available, which I haven't installed on local.

Why does the site work on local but not on dev?

Answer (score 0):

When Extra Block Types was installed locally via Home / Administration / List in Drupal, it installed Field Group automatically, bypassing Composer. The app  broke when I pushed to Pantheon Dev because Field Group was missing.

I uninstalled Field Group locally, installed it via Composer, then pushed back to Pantheon Dev. Problem solved.